# microsoft azure image lose all user accounts

Tags: azure, disk-image

At the moment we try Microsoft azure to check out the compatibility with our own products. Creating and installing our own software was pretty easy and everything works as a charm. Now we try to generate images to quick set up VMs for demo and customers.

I followed up the steps from MS here (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-capture-image/) (and a lot of google results too) and was wondering, why all user accounts are going to be deleted (and because of this RDP not working any longer). Our software installs an own web service (which runs under an own user) and some user-specific files, which will no longer work if the user account is deleted. On the other hand, no update for the software could be installed if you cannot access the VM, no customer can connect to VM or you could even not configure the software. What the heck?

Ok, now my questions

1. For what reason you create an image with NO user accounts? I can’t explain what this image is used for…
2. Is there any way to create a backup/image with user accounts to fast setup new VM
3. Is there any other way to fast setup an VM with preinstalled third-party software?

Comment: Sysprep deletes local administrator account. Is this the account you are asking about?

Comment: @proteus Not at all. In a first step we just use the local admin account because we play a litte bit around with azure. If I can kepp the local admin account it would be a great help. Otherwise, if I need to create an own account which can be kept, it's a solution for me, too.